# tiny java wifi device

Tags: java, wifi, device

I want to create a purpose built device capable of

1. running a java vm
2. connecting to a wireless network via dhcp
3. playing a simple sound

I'm looking for advice regarding who could

- what kind of devices are available pre-built
- who could manufacture a single device
- who could manufacture devices in small scale

any ideas appreciated!

Comment: running a JVM and small device are mutually exclusive requirements

Comment: Other than containing the word "Java", how is this question related to programming?

Comment: Java has been running on cell phones for years.

Comment: thanks thomas, fuzzy. good to see the community spirit still alive and well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know for sure about WiFi, the [Sun Spot](http://www.sunspotworld.com/) may do exactly what you want.

Comment: thanks jim, good link. you mentioned phones, i've never had a smart phone - anyone recommend a cheap one that integrates wifi and java well? i'd need a constant link to be compatible with my project.

Comment: although it's not extremely cost effective, this is the most relevant answer to the question. tick.